# How to handle HttpUrlConnection session management in Android?

Tags: android, session, playframework, playframework-2.0, httpurlconnection

How to handle HttpUrlConnection session management in Android? On server side I used Play framwework.On Successful login I stored Username,password in Shared preferences and then next time I enter to Application directly. I want to authenticate the Android Application User each and every time I send Http request to server.How to handle session on my HttpUrlConnection for my server communication?

- Can I use cookies for session management?
- On successful login create a token on server side and send back to android and store it in shared preference.Then send the token with each and every http request. After some period of time expire the token on server.After that the HttpRequest will be unAuthorised and I can display a login screen?

**Updated Code:**

```
httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            httpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length()));

            CookieManager msCookieManager = new CookieManager();
            CookieHandler.setDefault(msCookieManager);
            if(msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().size() > 0)
            {
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",TextUtils.join(",", msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()));
            }

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));
            bufferedWriter.write(postData);
            bufferedWriter.close();

            Log.d(TAG, "Wrote to Outputstream data success");

            int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(TAG,"responseCode ->" + responseCode);

            if(responseCode== HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = httpURLConnection.getHeaderFields();
                List<String> cookiesHeader = headerFields.get("Set-Cookie");

                if(cookiesHeader != null)
                {
                    for (String cookie : cookiesHeader)
                    {
                        msCookieManager.getCookieStore().add(null, HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
                    }
                }

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));

                String decodedLine;

                while ((decodedLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    loginResponse = loginResponse + decodedLine;
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
            }
```

Comment: Apache HttpClient already supported this for you. :) You can try it

Comment: I think Android Team discontinued support for HttpClient.So I want to use only HttpUrlConnection.

Comment: I'd probably just use a cookie.  Extract it from the response on a successful login, store it locally and send it back with each subsequent request.

Comment: @dave.c I tried like above code but cookiesHeader returns null.Check my code on my updated question

Comment: Are you sure the header field is called `Set-Cookie`?  Try printing all of the returned header names in case the cookie has a different name.